# What is the best way to collect errors and send a summary?

Tags: python

I have a script executing several independent functions in turn. I would like to collect the errors/exceptions happening along the way, in order to send an email with a summary of the errors.

What is the best way to raise these errors/exceptions and collect them, while allowing the script to complete and go through all the steps? They are independent, so it does not matter if one crashes. The remaining ones can still run.

```
def step_1():
    # Code that can raise errors/exceptions

def step_2():
    # Code that can raise errors/exceptions

def step_3():
    # Code that can raise errors/exceptions

def main():
    step_1()
    step_2()
    step_3()

    send_email_with_collected_errors()

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    main()
```

Should I wrap each step in a try..except block in the main() function? Should I use a decorator on each step function, in addition to an error collector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap each function in try/except, usually better for small simple scripts.

```
def step_1():
    # Code that can raise errors/exceptions

def step_2():
    # Code that can raise errors/exceptions

def step_3():
    # Code that can raise errors/exceptions

def main():
    try:
        step_1_result = step_1()
        log.info('Result of step_1 was {}'.format(result))
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Exception raised. {}'.format(e))
        step_1_result = e
        continue
    try:
        step_2_result = step_2()
        log.info('Result of step_2 was {}'.format(result))
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Exception raised. {}'.format(e))
        step_2_result = e
        continue

    try:
        step_3_result = step_3()
        log.info('Result of step_3 was {}'.format(result))
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Exception raised. {}'.format(e))
        step_3_result = e
        continue


    send_email_with_collected_errors(
        step_1_result,
        step_2_result,
        step_3_result
    )

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    main()
```

For something more elaborate you could use a decorator that'd construct a list of errors/exceptions caught. For example

```
class ErrorIgnore(object):
   def __init__(self, errors, errorreturn=None, errorcall=None):
      self.errors = errors
      self.errorreturn = errorreturn
      self.errorcall = errorcall

   def __call__(self, function):
      def returnfunction(*args, **kwargs):
         try:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
         except Exception as E:
            if type(E) not in self.errors:
               raise E
            if self.errorcall is not None:
               self.errorcall(E, *args, **kwargs)
            return self.errorreturn
      return returnfunction
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
exceptions = []

def errorcall(E, *args):
    print 'Exception raised {}'.format(E)
    exceptions.append(E)

@ErrorIgnore(errors=[ZeroDivisionError, ValueError], errorreturn=None, errorcall=errorcall)
def step_1():
   # Code that can raise errors/exceptions

...

def main():
    step_1()
    step_2()
    step_3()

    send_email_with_collected_errors(exceptions)

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I like your 'more elaborate' approach and sample code. It lets me collect exceptions that have been raised automatically or manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use simple `try` `except` statements and do logging for the exceptions that would be standard way to collect all your errors.

Comment: Thanks @armak. My point is, I want to send a single email at the end after collecting all the errors (not simply logging them to the console or a file).

Comment: @you can filter the log file on the basis of `error` statements and time and send that as a mail. as it would give you better design as you can send error for the last 3 executions or any other scenario you can think of.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. That is an option indeed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Use decorator in which you catch all exceptions and save it somewhere.
2. Add try/except everywhere.

Using decorator might be much better and cleaner, and code will be easier to maintain.

How to store errors? Your decision. You can add them to some list, create logging class receiving exceptions and get them after everything is done… Depends on your project and size of code.

Simple logging class:

```
class LoggingClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.exceptions = []

    def add_exception(self, exception):
        self.exceptions.append(exception)

    def get_all(self):
        return self.exceptions
```

Create instance of class in your script, catch exceptions in decorator and add them to class (however global variable might be also ok).

Comment: Thanks @sokoli. Would have an example of a basic architecture for "create logging class receiving exceptions and get them after everything is done…"?

Comment: Thanks for this. I am going to accept @Hevlastka's answer though, as he elaborated a bit more and provided full sample code.