# How to wrap functions in try/except and require a parameter

Tags: python, django

I want to wrap a bunch of functions in a try/except and have them email me a traceback when they fail. I'm using Django's ExceptionReporter, so I need the request object to send the traceback email. Some of the functions I want to wrap have the request object as a parameter already, but not all of them.

I was thinking about using a decorator for the try/except, but then it isn't clear that the request object is a required parameter for all the functions it decorates. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: The functions I'm trying to wrap are all just supplementary functions after the core stuff required for the response are done, so I don't want to use Django's automatic emailing that happens when returning a 500 error because of an uncaught exception. I suppose that opens up the possibility of running these methods as separate processes after returning the response, but that also gets complicated in Django.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767881/what-is-the-best-way-to-collect-errors-and-send-a-summary/39768492#39768492). Option 2 is what you'd be looking for I believe.

Comment: Doesn't django already send emails during errors?

Comment: Ah, forgot to add that I want to return 200 (because everything necessary for the response has already been done successfully). I'll update my question.

Comment: @Hevlastka The ExceptionReporter I want to use in the wrapper requires a runtime parameter, so I couldn't pass it through the decorator itself.

Comment: I think what I'll do is just make a wrapper that takes both a function and the request object and wrap all my function calls with the wrapper. I'd rather have to remember to use the wrapper every time than have to remember that a decorator is adding a required parameter.